# upper bound of a differential equation solution

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $A(t)$ be a bounded singular values matrix that is function of time, and $f(t)$ an $L^\infty$ function of time. And consider the ODE
$$
\dot x = A(t) x + f(t)
$$
How we can describe qualitatively  the magnitude that the euclidean norm $\| x \|$ reach in finite time $T$?

In other words, I wish to compute the upper bound of the euclidean norm a a time $T$ of the solution of an ODE without solving it. There is some related result from the Qualitative Theory of ODE's??

Comment: I edited your post to correct one *very* minor spelling error.  By the way, nice question, ***endorsed!***  I am preparing an answer.  Cheers!